# Using accepts_nested_attributes_for with rejects_if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using paperclip to attach photos to one of my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :data
end
```

How can I use reject_if to ignore data fields to which files are not uploaded by users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs['data'].blank? }
```

That should effectively ignore any data fields which are left blank by the user.